# Можно ли сравнить int и null?

Tags: java

Такая конструкция

```
int pages ;
if (pages = null) {
    pages = 25;
} else {
    pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
}
```

выдает ошибку в строке  `if (pages = null) {`  из-за несовпадения типов:

```
incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
```

Есть ли возможность сравнить целое число на значение null, или я пишу глупость?

Comment: У вас стоит оператор присваивания = а должен оператор сравнения ==

Comment: целое число (примитив `int`) не может быть `null`. `null` может быть ссылка на объект (напр. класса `Integer`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужно исправить код, то это будет так.

**(исправленный исходный код от автора)**

```
int pages;
if (pages == 0) {
    pages = 25;
} else {
    pages = request.getParameter();
}
Integer integer = pages;
```

int - это примитивный тип данных, поэтому нужно его сравнивать не с `null`, а `0`. Так как **в примитивных типах хранятся не ссылки** на область в памяти, где лежат объекты, **а сами значения**.

Может вам по началу будет удобно запомнить: все примитивные типы начинаются с маленькой буквы (boolean, int, double, float), а ссылочные с большой.

**(исправленный исходный код из комментариев)** - *спасибо* *`pavlofff`*

```
Integer pages;
try{
    pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
} catch (Exception e){
    pages = 25;
}
```

Comment: Если `pages` локальная переменная, то потребуется еще инициализация: `int pages = 0;`. С другой стороны в этом случае весь этот `if` теряет смысл.

Comment: @defaultlocale, я думаю что это кусок кода. Думаю это отдельный метод и pages параметр скорее всего,  по названию переменной это страницы.  Я не знаю конечного смысла что хочет сделать автор, только исправил код и объяснил почему нет. Ваш ответ мне нравится.

Comment: да, если присвоить переменной 0, то смысла от if не будет, будет всегда 25, а я выбираю это значение на странице в select-е и значение которое я выбрал уже не null, и должно выполнятся второе условие, но почему-то не работает

Comment: Какое второе условие? Аа, что конкретно не работает? Что возвращает или ошибку пишет?

Comment: я написал код так `Integer pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages")) ;
            if (pages == null) {
                pages = 25;
            } else {
                pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
            }`  выдает ошибку `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

Comment: Добавьте изменённый код

Comment: это значение я получаю из input-a на странице, input создаю с помощью javascript, идея такая я получаю значение `Integer pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages")) ;` если оно null, то переменной я передаю значение 25, а когда я меняю значение в select, выбираю например 100, это значение передается в инпут, и я в else его принимаю, как-то так

Comment: Страница сейчас не грузится и выдает `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`, а if не отрабатывает

Comment: Я исправил код, идея следующая вы приводите свое число к типу Integer если оно пустое, то присваиваете 25 страниц, если нет делаете с ним что вам нравится)

Comment: так и написал как вы поправили, страницу не отрисовывает , и выдает ошибку `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` на строке ` Integer pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));` получается оно видит null и сразу крашится, до if-a не доходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75885/discussion-between-timur-mukhortov-and--).

Comment: @СергейНиконенко NumberFormatException значит, что полученная строка не является числом типа `int`, что логично, если она равна `null`. Вам надо проверять на `null` результат, который вернула функция и вот если он не `null` - пытаться парсить к `int`: `String str = request.getParameter(); if (str == null) pages = 25 else pages = Integer.parseInt(str);`

Comment: @pavloff там не в этом дело, но замечание верное

Comment: @pavloff тогда только нужно будет проверять приводится ли строка к числу иначе опять formatexcep выпадет. Верно? вообще я бы это еще навсякий в try/catch завернул)

Comment: Если результат метода `request.getParameter()` какой то запрос, то нельзя делать два запроса, как в вашем исправленном ответе, так как каждый раз будет получено (может быть получено) иное значение. То есть нужно сохранить значение и с ним работать (как в моем комментарии), а не слать новые запросы (запрос в блоке else не будет проверен на null)

Comment: @pavlofff да, замечание хорошее, не подумал. сейчас исправим ответ

Comment: @pavloff добавил

Comment: тип String никогда не вернет `true` при `instanceof Integer` лучше просто парсинг проверять на экзепшен (try-catch) и в случае ошибки присваивать заданное значение. Тогда и на null проверять лишнее

Comment: @pavloff  вот так?        Integer pages;
        try{
            pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            pages = 25;
        }

Comment: @pavloff переделал еще раз

Answer (score 8):

> Есть ли возможность сравнить целое число на значение null?

Нельзя. Примитивные типы не могут принимать значение null. Соответственно, сравнивать с null их нельзя.

Как вариант, можно привести число к объекту-обертке:

```
Integer pages = null;
if(pages == null) { 
     ...
```

Приведение к null — не единственная проблема в Вашем примере:

- переменные в Java требуют инициализации: если `pages` — локальная переменная, то компилятор не даст ее использовать до того как ей присвоено значение, если же `pages` — поле класса, то ему будет присвоено значение по умолчанию — 0;
- сравнение в Java выполняется оператором `==`, Вы же пытаетесь присвоить `pages` значение и результат присвоения использовать в качестве аргумента `if`. Т.к. `if` принимает буллево значение, это приводит ко второй ошибке.